# Question where the question is an image

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question, images

Is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762121/can-someone-check-my-reduction-of-power-work
an allowed question?

The question is an image not in text 
- the image can be removed at some time and then the question loses its meaning.

But still I could not find a rule against it.

Or did I overlook something?

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/on-the-inclusion-of-pages-of-text-as-images-in-questions

Comment: I think you could find many examples of a question, where a newbie, who does not know TeX syntax, include math in the form of a picture. And usually some of more experienced users comes and help him with editing the post.

Comment: And you could also find many posts, where a user has scanned something hand-written, as in your example. Just browse through the results of [this google search](http://images.google.com/images?q=site:math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12289/are-pictures-of-hand-written-drawings-allowed. I'd rather see a clear picture of the OP's work than a mess of illegible attempted math-writing without MathJax. I (usually) don't mind transcribing a new user's picture into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the image can be removed at some time

Not if the image is hosted on `stack.imgur.com`; those images are stable and cannot be removed by users. Thus, I suggest re-uploading off-site images to `stack.imgur`. This is easy to do:

1. Click `edit`
2. Copy the URL of the image from the body of the post
3. Click the `Image` button in the toolbar.
4. Select "from the web" and paste the URL.

If the image contains scanned text, it may be appropriate to eventually type it out, but this should not always be the editor's top priority. Many such questions end up being deleted (as was the one to which you linked).