# Question on proofs with text-&-LaTeX images

Tags: discussion, mathjax, policy, images, mathoverflow

Two days ago, I saw [a stochastic process question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2428120/290189) which contained images that could be *completely* $\rm\TeX$ified.  Based on several related questions found on this site, I think those images should be converted to $\rm\TeX$(t) so that the *whole* [question would be searchable](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20334/290189).  In *principle*, the question itself should ["contain enough stand-alone context"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).  (See remarks below.)

Though the images uploaded on `i.stack.imgur.com` have [*stable* URLs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13459/290189), are they regarded as "external content" as in the [accepted answer for this MathMeta.SE question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189)?

According to answer for the question *[Should I edit a question everytime I see an image in it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11696/290189)*, every text-and-$\rm\LaTeX$ image should be converted to $\rm\TeX$(t) no matter how old the post is.  As a result, I copied the following comment from the [comment template list](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4925/290189) *without* much thinking in order to ask the question writer to typeset the math.

> Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

In retrospect, I should have used another one from D.W.

> Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.

Even though the uploaded images in the question are *not* scanned pages, I believe that the arguments from the Meta.SE moderator for the question *[Allowed to post scanned page from text book on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305)* can be applied to this situation.

What can be done to stop the question writer from using this *"shortcut to not having to type anything*" if he/she refuses to typeset the material using MathJax?

Since this question is cross-posted on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/281076/14319), can the arguments of the Meta.SE moderator be also applied on MO?

Remarks: I understand that in *practice*, geometry questions with some geometric figure(s) are acceptable since we won't expect users to write them in an ancient-Greek style.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much that we can do except downvoting and closing their stuff with a comment that asks them to replace their text images with the appropriate text.  When they've made the demanded changes, the downvote and close vote would be retracted.